# Howto flush "select-State"?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm writing a powershell script to get some data from a range of dell notebooks, like mac addresses, service tags, etc... I found that when I use [Get-Data] | select [..] in a .ps1-File the state of the first select carries over to other select statements.

Given this code:

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select serialnumber from Win32_Bios" | select SerialNumber
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select serialnumber from Win32_Bios" | select SerialNumber
```

When I run each line separately in the powershell I get this output:

```
PS C:\Users\Vinzenz\Data\Code\spass_powershell> Get-WmiObject -Query "Select serialnumber from Win32_Bios" | select SerialNumber

SerialNumber
------------
[redacted]


PS C:\Users\Vinzenz\Data\Code\spass_powershell> Get-WmiObject -Query "Select serialnumber from Win32_Bios" | select SerialNumber

SerialNumber
------------
[redacted]
```

When I put the code in a .ps1-File I get this output:

```
PS C:\Users\Vinzenz\Data\Code\spass_powershell> .\rechnerdata.ps1

SerialNumber
------------
[redacted]
[redacted]
```

Is there a way to flush this "state", because this behaviour stops from using the nice formatting "select" gives me.

I found this behaviour in this script:

```
## ServiceTag
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select serialnumber from Win32_Bios" | select SerialNumber

## Mac-Addresses
$adapters = @()
# get all adapters with a mac and replace : with -
Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration | select description, macaddress | where {$_.macaddress} | Foreach {$_.macaddress = $_.macaddress -replace ':','-'; $adapters += $_;}  
$adapters | select description, macaddress;
```

When I run it as a script file I get this output:

```
PS C:\Users\Vinzenz\Data\Code\spass_powershell> .\rechnerdata.ps1

SerialNumber
------------
[redacted]








PS C:\Users\Vinzenz\Data\Code\spass_powershell>
```

Comment: It's not `Select-Object` (`select` is an alias) that gives you the nice formatting - it's `Format-Table` which is implicitly called

Comment: That being said, if the purpose of your script is to collect information from many machines and store them somewhere (ie. in a file/spreadsheet or an asset database), you should probably not care too much about output formatting - output formatting is only meaningful to *humans*, not fit for exchanging data

Comment: Currently the script needs to be human readable, as we're copy'n'pasting the data to our spreadsheets. I would to fully automate this process in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't `Select-Object`'s doing. This is just PowerShell combining multiple objects being output if they are of the same type. You can see the same when you're doing `Get-ChildItem` which would be seriously weird if the headers would be output once for each item.

You can »fix« (for certain interpretations of *fix*) this, by explicitly using `Format-Table`:

```
gwmi win32_bios | select serialnumber | ft
gwmi win32_bios | select serialnumber | ft
```

Normally the *entire* output of a command gets piped into something appropriate for the given type, which means you get only a single `Format-Table` for your script, unless you do it yourself.

Comment: So select pushes the data into some sort of global Format-Table object and if theres none it creates one?

Comment: @vinzBad No, `Select-Object` doesn't do anything, other than creating a new object with the `serialnumber` property. This object "bubbles up" to the host (`powershell.exe`) and *its* default behavior is to pipe objects with less than five properties through `Format-Table` before outputting it to the console buffer

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks :) So `powershell.exe` saves the `Format-Table` and when the next object "bubbles up" which doesn't match the columns it silently ignores it?

Comment: @vinzBad: Sort of, yes. You can quickly test this: `new-object psobject -property @{foo=1;bar=2};new-object psobject -property @{a=1;b=2}` which will output only the first object here, while »ignoring« the second.

Comment: Powershell expects a stream of the same type of objects as the output of a function or script, so it uses the first object as the master to decide which columns will be displayed. :-)